# Prove that $\dim(T) = \dim(V) \dim(W) − \dim(X)(\dim(W) − \dim(Y))$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are vector subspaces of $V$ and $W$ respectively.

Show that $$T =\{\alpha \in L(V,W)|\alpha(x)\in Y\text{ for all }x\in X\}$$
is a vector subspace of $L(V,W)$.

Prove that
$\dim(T) = \dim(V) \dim(W) − \dim(X)(\dim(W) − \dim(Y))$.

To show vector space is quite easy and I was trying to use the rank-nullity theorem to solve the second part, but I did not know how to start with because T is a set of linear Transformations.

Another method I tried is to express the basis of T but I still cannot solve.

Here is my proof after the suggestions.
$$T=\begin{bmatrix} [\alpha]_{B_Y},_{B_X} & [\alpha]_{B_W},_{B_{V-X}}\\ 0 & \end{bmatrix}$$
Then dim(T) = dim(X)dim(Y) + (dim(V) - dim(X)) dim(W) Then by simplification we can get the result.

Comment: Are the vector spaces finite dimensional?

Comment: If $Y'$ is a subspace of $W$ such that $W=Y\oplus Y'$, then the result follows from the fact that $L(V,W)=T\oplus L(X,Y')$. But I'm not sure about my proof of this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take special bases for $V$ and $W$. Take the basis of $X$ and expand it to the basis of $V$, i.e. take such vectors $$B=\{v_1,v_2\dots, v_{\dim X}, v_{\dim X + 1}\dots v_{\dim V} \}$$

so that $\{v_1,\dots, v_{\dim X}\}$ is a basis for $X$ and that $B$ is a basis for $V$. Do the same for $W$.

Any linear transformation in $L(V,W)$ will then have a matrix of the form

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\ C & D\end{bmatrix}$$

Then, think about the the matrices that represent linear transformations from $T$. Which values of $M$ must be zero?

Comment: Yes it is finite dimensional.